# Split string by comma only when is coma outside of double-quotes c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

```
"TIMESTAMP (UTC)","LOG TYPE","DEVICE TYPE","DEVICE","MESSAGE","PARAMETERS"
"2014-08-12 17:30:34.437","Warning","DiverGate","141403G00294","Diver gate(s) did not connect since","2014-08-08 06:37:31 (UTC)"
"2014-08-12 17:30:34.577","Warning","DiverGate","141403G00120","Diver gate(s) did not connect since","2014-08-08 06:46:22 (UTC)"
"2014-08-13 06:45:18.890","Error","DiverGate","141403G00294","Was set to inactive, because it did not connect since","2014-08-08 06:37:31 (UTC)"
"2014-08-13 07:00:18.903","Error","DiverGate","141403G00120","Was set to inactive, because it did not connect since","2014-08-08 06:46:22 (UTC)"
```

This is my .csv file and i need to read informations from file, but I need to split informations with comma who is outside double quotes, because in some other files I can find comma into some informations, especially in message, log type,...

```
 string url = @"E:\Project.csv";
 Stream stream = File.Open(url, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            string[] lines = null;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
                lines = Regex.Split(str, //what expression is going here);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> They do not `consume` characters in the string, but only assert whether a `match` is possible or not.

```
(?<="),(?=")
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iO6iZ9/1) and tested at [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22)%2c(%3f%3d%22)&i=%22a%2cb%22%2c%22c%22%2c%22d%22)

Pattern explanation is very simple

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    "                        '"'
  )                        end of look-behind
  ,                        ','
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    "                        '"'
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: This is great, but i have one more problem. When this get to end of one row (i have it in this case 4), I get `\"PARAMETERS\"\r\n\"2014-08-12 17:30:34.437\""`. I unederstand what is meaning \r\n\, but how to instead \r\n\ i put all text right from \r\n\ into new string?

Comment: [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22)%2c(%3f%3d%22)&i=%22a%22%2c%22b%22%2c%22c%22%2c%22d%22%2c%22e%22%0d%0a%22f%22%2c%22g%22%2c%22h%22%2c%22i%22%2c%22j%22%0d%0a%221%22%2c%222%22%2c%223%22%2c%224%22%2c%225%22%0d%0a%226%22%2c%227%22%2c%228%22%2c%229%22%2c%220%22) This is how its like in my string array. Every fourth index is seems like this

Answer (score 3):

This is just basic CSV parsing, and there are libraries out there to do it already. I would recommend taking a look at [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) which I've used before rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

You can include this in your project really easily by using the Package Manager Console and typing:

> Install-Package CsvHelper

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rolling out your own CSV parser, use existing libraries. There is [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) class which is available with Visual Basic, Just add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`  under project references then you can do:

```
TextFieldParser textFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(@"E:\Project.csv");
textFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
textFieldParser.SetDelimiters(",");
while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
{
    string[] values = textFieldParser.ReadFields();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("---", values));//printing the row
}
textFieldParser.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can also use this regex

```
var result = Regex.Split(samplestring, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
```